# Why does the post I just voted to close only have one vote showing, when another user previously selected a duplicate as well?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

This just happened:

[Go: handle Gorilla mux empty variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26181282/go-handle-gorilla-mux-empty-variable/26182039#26182039)

When I voted to close for duplication, @SvenGrosen had already cast a vote and hence I got the link suggested in the "duplicated thread selection" view. After casting my vote I still only see 1 vote-to-close.

Clarification: when I clicked on "close", I saw 0 votes cast. After submitting my own vote I see 1. Yet I did get auto-complete when submitting and @SvenGrosen confirms he had also voted.

Maybe there was a change? Maybe it's a feature? Maybe a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sven Grosen does not yet have enough reputation to vote to close, they can only **flag** the post for closure. You need [3000 points for the close vote privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

As such they never cast a closure vote. Flagging instead brings the post to the *Close Review queue*, and flagging as a duplicate does add the automatic comment.

Comment: Makes sense. He actually said "flagged" and I assumed he meant "voted to close", silly me.